# What is the difference between Javascript's native `instanceof` operator and MooTools' `instanceOf` function?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, mootools

MooTools has its own `instanceOf(instance, Type)` function.
I can only assume that it does SOMETHING different from Javascript's native `instanceof` operator, but I cannot seem to figure out what.

Can anyone explain the difference or the purpose of the `instanceOf()` function?

Comment: One is a function and the other is an operator. :)

Comment: The relevant bit of the mootools source lives [here](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Core/Core.js#L47).

Comment: @user6607 You forgot to mention that one has a capital O, the other has a lowercase o.

Comment: @RichardTowers Sidenote: I didn't know you could link to a specific line number!  Cool!

Answer (score 3):

`instanceOf` is complimentary to `typeOf` which are internal MooTools functions that do a better job of Type traversal than their native counterparts.

typeOf is slightly more useful in that:

```
typeof []; // object
typeOf([]); // array
typeof new Date(); // object
typeOf(new Date()); // date
```

instanceOf is mostly to be used for Class, though it works for Types constructors also.

eg.

```
var foo = new Class(),
    bar = new Class({
        Extends: foo
    });

var foobar = new bar();

instanceOf(foobar, bar); // true
// but also due to Extends prototype chain and the constructor:
instanceOf(foobar, foo); // true

// as well as standard behaviour like
instanceOf([], Array); // true
instanceOf(4, Number); // true vs 4 instanceof Number == false
```

see the source:
https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Core/Core.js#L47-58

you may notice a lot of the constructors for Types in mootools decorate objects to ease duck typing so typeOf and instanceOf work with an actual meaningful result.

also read [mootools Type function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987173/mootools-type-function)

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I definitely understand difference between `typeOf` and `typeof`; the latter only gives 5 results while the former gives 20 results, which is a pretty big difference.  

But are you suggesting that the only purpose of `instanceOf` is to compare native types to Number and String?

Comment: Also, looking through the `instanceOf` source code, I see 2 things: **1.** a manual traversal of the inheritance chain; **2.** some `ltIE8` code.  I would assume that the native `instanceof` works identical to #1, so it would seem to me that the only purpose of `instanceOf` is for `ltIE8`?

Comment: it's the check for `$constructor` which decorates all objects that are via a class prototype that allows it to find if a class instance is a child of a particular constructor. the other stuff is a bonus, imo. like i said, it's mostly used for Class operations.

Comment: So would `foobar instanceof foo` be false? I always assumed MooTools inheritance is an extension of native Javascript inheritance, therefore `instanceof` should behave correctly with MooTools classes.  What am I missing?  **Edit:** I just tested http://jsfiddle.net/RbTUb/, and `foobar instanceof foo` is indeed `true`.

Comment: `var foo = new Class(); console.log(foo instanceof Class); console.log(instanceOf(foo, Class));` - not a native instanceof Class but it is. instanceOf works with mootools Type in edgecases where the operator fails but this is one of the few real cases. `Class` is a `Type` via the Type constructor so it's treated like a Native... I can't think of many usecases where instanceOf is required outside of the Type for Class argument check itself...

Answer (score 2):

At the very least:

```
> "" instanceof String
false
> instanceOf("", String)
true
```

Comment: What does `instanceOf();` do differently?

Comment: +1 Good to know!  `instanceOf()` compares native types, whereas `instanceof` only compares "boxed" types.  I'm assuming the same goes for `5 instanceof Number`.